# Deploying war file in STS using gradle

Tags: java, deployment, war, gradle, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a web project in STS, that iam looking to deploy in Tomcat. The build file for the project is written in GRADLE. Using GRADLE'S build script, a war file is generated in build/libs.

But STS looks for the war file in workspace/metadata/plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/ folder.

Now If I manually copy the generated WAR file from build/libs to this workspace/metadata/plugins folder, and then start the tomcat, everything works fine but I am not able to debug using breakpoints in STS.

How do I make sure that the war file from build/libs gets moved to workspace/metadata/plugins folder?

And, Why is STS looking to find the war in workspace/metadata/plugins folder. As the app-server is tomcat, should it not be looking in Tomcat/webapps folder to find the war?

Comment: Intellij IDEA does the job well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a eclipse fan nowadays but did you run eclipse plugin? you can add it to the gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

and then just run

```
gradle eclipse
```

check [Eclipse Plugin](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe STS deploys/runs your war file directly.  That is, if you select the project and say "Run on Server", STS/eclipse will generate an exploded war to the wtp.deploy directory defined.   You can control/alter this by editing the "run configuration" for your server.  Just go to the "Arguments" tab and change the setting for the "-Dwtp.deploy".

You should really only use this STS mechanism for development purposes - as it is invaluable for that.   To deploy an actual warfile to Tomcat you have a variety of options.  You can start a tomcat instance with the manager UI enabled and upload the war file from the Tomcat GUI, you can just manually drop the war file into Tomcat's deployment area, or probably your best option - extend your gradle build scripts to include deploying the generated war file to a tomcat server.  Hope this helps some.